# Combining CakePHP and Wordpress .htaccess rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-1.3

I've got a problem that seems relatively straightforward but I don't know exactly how to get mod_rewrite and .htaccess to behave the way I want them to. First off, I have a Wordpress install in the /webroot directory of my CakePHP app (in the subfolder "blog"). That works fine, as in, I can access:

*site.com/blog/

site.com/blog/about/* 

etc...

Since I would like wordpress to power a few static pages on my site, I would like some of these Wordpress pages to have "root" level URLs, e.g.
site.com/about (which would actually be the WP page /blog/about)

If I have permalinks turned off on my WP site (i.e. the .htaccess file in /webroot/blog is empty), then this works pretty well. In my /app .htaccess file, I use:

`RewriteRule ^about /blog/index.php?page_id=2 [NC,L]`

Then I can go to *site.com/about* and it works. But, I would prefer to use "pretty permalinks" in my WP site, so that once you get to the WP site and you're clicking around, the links don't look like "index.php?page_id=...". The problem is that if I turn permalinks on, when I go to *site.com/about* it will redirect (i.e. change my address bar) to *site.com/blog/about* which I don't really want. If I instead use:

`RewriteRule ^about /blog/about [NC,L]`

It does take me to my WP site, but with a 404 page not found. I'm guessing this all has something to do with the fact that my rewrite rule is directing to WP, which then applies its own rewrite rules.

So, the bottom line is that I would essentially like to "hardcode" particular URLs like *site.com/about* and have them be hooked up to WP pages, while preserving the hardcoded URL in the address bar. 
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I ended up not using .htaccess rules to do this (though I would still be curious if my original question does have an answer). I created a separate connection in database.php to connect to my WP database, and I now just have a WordpressController which pulls in my posts and injects them into a standard Cake view. That way I can use Cake routing to control these URLs, as well as utilizing my same Cake layout.

Comment: I'm trying to do almost the same thing and im very interested to know more about how you got this working. Could you possibly provide some more details, or maybe some code from your WordpressController?

Comment: You can go through this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974730/wordpress-inside-cakephp/33097844#33097844

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `RewriteRule ^about /blog/about [NC]`

Comment: Same result as before: goes to WP, but with a 404. I've also tried `[R,NC,L]` which redirects to the proper page but also changes the URL to '/blog/about' which, again, I don't want.