# Wordpress inside Cakephp

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp

I have installed Wordpress inside Cakephp's `/app/webroot/blog/` folder and changed the wordpress permalink settings to Month and name (eg. `http://abc.com/blog/2013/02/sample-post/`).

Now when i am viewing a post i am getting Missing Controller(Error: BlogController could not be found).

I want to change the cakephp routes so that anything with `/blog/*` will point to webroot blog folder.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want Wordpress in the `webroot` directory? Is outside also a possibility?

Comment: As per the clients requirement it should be kept inside webroot.

Comment: in this case try to modify the .htaccess in a way that will ignor specifically blog and match the physical location instead of looking for Query String of the index file that might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we change the permalink settings of Wordpress, it generates a `.htaccess` file, if there is required permission else we have to create it.

In the above case there was no `.htaccess` file inside `/blog/` folder. I created it with the following mod_rewrite rules as provided by Wordpress while changing permalink settings.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

After this every thing works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to put the blog folder in webroot folder. You can access your folder by making slight changes in your .htaccess file. Just put your wordpress folder on root of cakephp with app folder and change .htaccess as given below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (blog/.*) $1 [L] # adjust the regex to what you want.
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna. I have tried this but it is showing an 500 internal server error when i am accessing a post page(/blog/2013/02/this-is-a-post/). However the clients requirement is, it should be kept inside webroot.

Comment: for that you need to change rewrite base path in blog folders htacces

Comment: Yes Krishna, you are correct. It works after changing rewrite base path in blog folders .htacces. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the above codes but none work for me.. then i found something by my own and it worked..So here it is ,, hope this will help some.

First Add the WordPress folder inside the webroot folder as blog. Inside blog paste the WordPress directories and files.. install the WordPress.. Now you will see in the WordPress admin general settings WordPress Address as http://cakephp/blog/app/webroot/blog, Change it to http://cakephp/blog. Save it ..

Now look for the .htaccess file in WordPress install root folder change RewriteBase and RewriteRule (last one ) to RewriteBase /blog/ and RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /blog/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. There are various htaccess files. Could you please help me with correct file path..?

Comment: Please go through the answer..i have mentioned it now