# Installing Wordpress inside CakePHP 3

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to have Wordpress inside CakePHP 3. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14976379/679318), but it is not working. Two problems:

- If I try `domain.com/wordpress/`, I get stuck in this [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974730/wordpress-inside-cakephp#comment21033920_14976379): `500 internal server error`
- If I try `domain.com/wordpress` (without trailing slash), it is processed like a cakePHP request and I get `Error: WordpressController could not be found`

I have also tried with bedrock, a modified version of WP. But no luck.

The folder structure (with original WP):

```
www/
├─── cake/
│   ├─── webroot/
│   │    └── .htaccess
│   ├─── wordpress/
│   │    └── .htaccess
│   └── .htaccess
└── .htaccess
```

And the various `htaccess` files:

**www/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (wordpress/.*) $1 [L] # adjust the regex to what you want.
    RewriteRule    ^$ cake/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) cake/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**www/cake/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /cake/
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**www/cake/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cake/webroot/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+cake/webroot/([^\s&]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**www/cake/wordpress/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/log/error.log**

```
[core:error] [pid 5506] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:55118] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

*LogLevel is already set to debug.

Comment: Take a look to `www/error_log` and paste here what you find out.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar done

Comment: Try cranking up the trace log level in order to get details about the rewrite flow: **http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging**

Comment: I changed the debug to `trace3` and checked the log. I don't know why, but apache was looking for the wordpress directoty in `/var/www/html/`, when I set everything to be `/var/www/html/cake/`. After moving one level up, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **www/cake/wordpress/.htaccess** should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cake/wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /cake/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit

Ok, here's the problem. *http://example.com/* points to *www/* directory. And you want *http://example.com/wordpress/* to point to *www/cake/wordpress*. You'll need to adequeate **www/.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/wordpress(/.*)?$ /cake/wordpress$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule    ^$ cake/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) cake/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No luck. Still 500 error and same thing in the log.

Comment: What's your PHP version? Does the log entry's timestamp match actual time?

Comment: Can you run any other php script in **www/cake/wordpress/**, say, *test.php* with `phpinfo();` function in it?

Comment: Now both (with and without trailing slash) gives controller not found.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. The .htaccess was right. It wasn't working because the folder was in the wrong place.